# Facebook Graph API SEO Comments and Profanity Filter

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments, facebook-social-plugins

I'm  trying to integrate the Facebook comments left on our site in a way in which the content can be crawled by search engines and also for people (although I highly doubt there will be many) who don't have Javascript enabled on their browser.

Currently our Facebook comments are displayed via the use of the Facebook comment social plugin (using the `<fb:comments href="MY_URL" num_posts="50" width="665"></fb:comments>` tag). This ends up rendering an iFrame (which are mostly ignored by search engine crawlers) so the plan is to render this information and format it with basic HTML. To do this, the comments are pulled using the Graph API - this is then only be displayed to crawlers and people with Javascript disabled.

This all works nicely using the Graph API call (https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=MY_URL), parsing the JSON result and displaying it on the page. The problem is that the `<fb:comments>` approach filters our results based on a blacklist we have set up on one of our Facebook Apps. The AppId with the relevant blacklist is stored on the page using metadata (`<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP_ID"/>`) which the `<fb:comments>` control obviously must somehow use to filter the comments.

The problem is the Graph API method does not filter any results as I guess no blacklist (or App Id containing a blacklist) is specified. Does anyone know how to specify a Facebook App ID to the API call URL or of another way to not fetch commnents back that violate the terms of the blacklist?

On a side note, I know the debate about filtering content in comments rages on but it is a management decision to implement the blacklist, and one that I have no influence in changing - just incase anyone felt the need to explain the reasons why content filtering is or isn't a good idea!

Any thoughts on a solution?

Comment: I don't have any pages set up to test this at all, but I'm wondering what happens when you use [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/) to query the comments? Is there a flag on the blacklisted comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to access a filtered list of comments using the API - it might be a reasonably request to have this in the API - you should file a wishlist item in [Facebook's bug tracker](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs)

Otherwise, the only solution I can think of is to implement your own filter on your side when retrieving and displaying the comments from the API.

According to the [Comments plugin documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) the filter on Facebook's side is implemented as a simple substring match, so it should be trivial to implement.
A fairly simple regular expression match should be able to check each comment against a relatively long list quickly.

(Unfortunately, the tradeoff here is that implementing a filter is easy, but you'd also need to write an interface so that whoever's updating the list of disallowed words can maintain the list for both the Facebook plugin, and your own filtering.)

Quote from docs:

> The comment is checked via substring matching. This means if you blacklist the
> word 'at', if the comment contains the sequence 'a' 't' anywhere it will be
> marked with limited visibility; e.g. if the comment contained the words 'bat',
> 'hat', 'attend', etc it would be caught.

Comment: Yep, you're spot on here. A custom filter looks like the best option and seems to be acceptable to the decision-makers here! Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure there is no current way of doing this from the graph API, the only thing I can suggest is taking the blacklist and build your own filter